# Build React components library with Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm currently building a library of React components and bundling it with Webpack 4.

Everything works just fine from building the library's bundle to publishing it on an npm registry.

But then, I'm not able to import any of its components in an other React application and get this error message at runtime:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

And here is the related code:

A dumb component from my components library:
`button/index.js`

```
import React from "react";

const Button = () => <button>Foobar</button>;

export { Button };
```

The main entry point of my library `index.js`:

```
import { Button } from "./src/components/Button";

export { Button };
```

My Webpack config `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
    library: ""
  }
};
```

And finally, the import of this component in an other application:

```
import { Button } from "my-design-system";
```

I guess I'm missing something in my Webpack config or one of the property may be wrong, but after reading multiple posts and tutorials, I can't figure which one.

Comment: Try changing `export { Button };` to `export  Button ;`

Comment: I think this is not a valid syntax. I Also tried to export it as default with `export default Button` and import it with `import Button from 'lib'` but same result.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're exporting your library as `commonjs` and trying to import it via `import/export` syntax. You should change your output to

```
output: {
  filename: "index.js",
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  libraryTarget: "umd",
  library: "my-design-system"
}
```

Found a lot of info here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

Comment: Thanks, this is working ! I tried `umd` before but forgot to set the `library` property to the name of my library. I'm not really sure of what in means under the hood...

Comment: Under the hood workings of webpack are interesting, but will not yield too much info for you for your react library. One more point to remember is you'll need to [externalize](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#externalize-lodash) react. It means that you expect your library's user to install react and you won't bundle it along with your library. Also, take a look at [create-react-library](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library) if you don't want to bother about these configs and just build your lib.

Comment: I have done this by my `import`s are still coming as undefined?  I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to find practical examples for this scenario.  What am I missing?

Comment: @TomPietrosanti hard to say! Maybe ask a question? Webpack problems can be hard to diagnose

Answer (score 4):

What I would do is to export your components as default and then re-export as named from `index.js`:

```
/// Button.js
import React from "react";

const Button = () => <button>Foobar</button>;

export default Button ;
```

```
// index.js
export { default as Button } from "./src/components/Button";
```

Then you can do

```
import { Button } from "my-design-system";
```

Also make sure you have `main` set up, pointing to your `index.js`, in your design system's `package.json`

Additionally, if you still want to have named exports in some of your components, you can export everything from that component file:

```
//index.js
export * from "./src/components/ComponentWithNamedExports";
```

Either way you will make sure there's always one point of export for all your components.

EDIT: As noted in by Maaz Syed Adeeb, you have wrong `libraryTarget` in your config. I'd remove both `libraryTarget` and `library` from there.

Comment: I'm still having the same error with your solution. Also, I don't really see what is fundamentally different from my code as we are both just exporting components.

I also tried to set the `main` property to `index.js` although I think it should be set to `dist/index.js` right ?

Comment: Ah, yes, `dist/index.js`. You also might need to add a `module` prop to package.json with the same path.

Comment: As @maaz-syed-adeeb mentioned, my problem was coming from my webpack configuration. Thanks anyway for taking the time.

Comment: Any git repo for example ?